# How to make a html a href link change a php value. Or something that will do something like that

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, href

I have a spot on my website that I want to use to either show one php file of information or if a link is clicked(not a button) a different display of information is shown.

the idea is to make the link change a value from 0 to 1.

if the value is 0 show page 1
if the value is 1 show page 2

I am storing the links in a php string. Then displaying either one php file or another based on which link is clicked.

```
$userlinks = '<a href="user_profile.php?id=' . $userid . '">Profile</a> &bull; <a>' .     $ip . '</a> &bull; <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';
```

instead of making the Profile link go to user_profile.php, I want the clicking of the link to change a value from 0 to 1.

Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Do you need this to be done with AJAX? Or is a page refresh fine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET variables in your link to achieve this affect. When building your link, do something like:

```
$userlinks = 'user_profile.php?id=' . $userid . '&page=1';
```

By passing a number in a GET variable, it can be accessed in your script like:

```
switch($_GET['page'])
{
   case "1":
      // Show page 1
      break;
   case "2":
      // Show page 2
      break;    
   default:
      // Show error
      echo("Page Does Not Exist!");
}
```